# converting a sequential number to a date

Tags: sql

converting a number to a date.  I am converting isam files to sql files and having issues with dates.  My dates are a sequential number starting with 1/1/20 as 1.  So today (3/2/17) is stored as 35491.  I want to store the dates in sql as a real date (yyyy-mm-dd).  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Add a tag to this question for your specific DB platform

Answer (score 2):

In SQL server you would go like this:

```
select dateadd(day, 35491, '1920-01-01')
```

In MySQL:

```
select date_add('1920-01-01 00:00:00', interval 35491 day)
```

Comment: From my run on SQL Server, to get '2017-03-02' as a result, you need to add 35490.